# eliminar key duplicada de un multi array

Tags: php, array, php7

hola a todos tengo el siguiente array pero necesito excluir del array definitivo los arrays con el `key` repetido en este ejemplo el `wel`

```
array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "eng"
  "count" => "299"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "wel"
  "count" => "84"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "dut"
  "count" => "8"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "wel"
  "count" => "1"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "enm"
  "count" => "1"
]
```

debería quedar así:

```
array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "eng"
  "count" => "299"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "wel"
  "count" => "84"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "dut"
  "count" => "8"
]

array:3 [▼
  "facet" => "language"
  "key" => "enm"
  "count" => "1"
]
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, si lo eliminas, por qué te quedas con el que tiene count 84 y no con el de count 1?

Comment: el count no importa en este caso

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo algo así:

```
<?php

$a=[
    [
      "facet" => "language",
      "key" => "eng",
      "count" => "299",
    ],
    [
      "facet" => "language",
      "key" => "wel",
      "count" => "84",
    ],
    [
      "facet" => "language",
      "key" => "dut",
      "count" => "8",
    ],
    [
      "facet" => "language",
      "key" => "wel",
      "count" => "1",
    ],
    [
      "facet" => "language",
      "key" => "enm",
      "count" => "1",
    ]
];

foreach($a as $ai)
    $b[$ai['key']]=$ai;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($b);
echo '</pre>';
```

De forma que explotemos la unicidad de los índices de un array con:

```
foreach($a as $ai) $b[$ai['key']]=$ai;
```

Para obtener el resultado:

```
Array
(
    [eng] => Array
        (
            [facet] => language
            [key] => eng
            [count] => 299
        )

    [wel] => Array
        (
            [facet] => language
            [key] => wel
            [count] => 1
        )

    [dut] => Array
        (
            [facet] => language
            [key] => dut
            [count] => 8
        )

    [enm] => Array
        (
            [facet] => language
            [key] => enm
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Espero que sea el que esperabas. Si quieres eliminar los índices puedes utilizar:

```
foreach($b as $bi) $c[]=$bi;
```

Obteniendo un array enumerado de arrays asociativos.